# Bootstrap modal as dropdown

Tags: bootstrap-modal

```
    <div id="lastcolumn" class="col-md-3">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
            <li class="llogin"><a class="mlogin" data-target="#loginmodal" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span>Login</a></li>
                        <div class="modal" id="loginmodal" tabindex="-1">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <form>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="Username">Username</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="text" class="form-control">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="Password">Password</label>
                                                <input type="Password" name="text" class="form-control">
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
            <li class="lsignup"><a class="msignup"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span>Signup</a></li>
            <li class="lcart"><a class="mcart"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart pull-right"></span>Item</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I want to show bootstrap modal as dropdown under login currently my modal is showing in middle of the screen what i have to do to achieve the desired behaviour, kindly help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52I6d.png)

Comment: use `CSS` and assign the correct style for your `#loginmodal` position

Comment: i did but not working do not know what's wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `.modal` div in the `li` that you want to attach the modal with. Then define `position:relative;` for that `li` and `position:absolute;` for that `.modal`.

Here's a working snippet. I removed the `.modal-backdrop` and edited padding and margin for modal.  You can ignore them since they are not relevant to the basic problem.

```css
.nav.navbar-nav li{
  float:left;
}
.nav.navbar-nav li a.mlogin{
  position:relative;
}
div.modal#loginmodal{
  position:absolute;
  width:200px;
  height:300px;
  top:30px;
  left:0;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
div.modal#loginmodal .modal-footer{
  padding:5px;
  margin:0;
}
div.modal#loginmodal .modal-body{
  padding:10px 20px;
  margin:0;
}
div.modal#loginmodal .modal-header{
  padding:5px 20px;
  margin:0;
}
.modal-backdrop{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <div id="lastcolumn" class="col-md-3">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
      <li class="llogin"><a class="mlogin" data-target="#loginmodal" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span>Login</a>
               <div class="modal" id="loginmodal" tabindex="-1">
         <div class="modal-dialog">
           <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">
               <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-body">
               <form>
                 <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="Username">Username</label>
                   <input type="text" name="text" class="form-control">
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="Password">Password</label>
                   <input type="Password" name="text" class="form-control">
                 </div>
               </form>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-footer">
               <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </li>
     <li class="lsignup"><a class="msignup"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span>Signup</a></li>
     <li class="lcart"><a class="mcart"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart pull-right"></span>Item</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks :-) Kitty Cat you did it. <3